# Python Implementation of MATLAB's Canny Filter

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

Calling the following function in MATLAB applies the Canny filter to an image:

```
edges = edge(image, 'Canny');
```

There are two Python functions I know of that implement the Canny filter:

```
import cv2

edges = cv2.Canny(image)
```

and

```
from skimage import feature

edges = feature.canny(image)
```

However, neither of these Python functions is capable of computing the filter's high and low threshold in the same manner MATLAB does.  According to [this neuroimaging paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811908001171),

> . . . the default MATLAB algorithm [generates] the two thresholds such that the high threshold is calculated to be the lowest value at which no more than 30% of the pixels are detected as edges, and the low threshold is defined as 40% of the high threshold.

Is there a Python implementation that can do this?

Comment: The scikit-image source is here: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/feature/_canny.py  It should be fairly easy to adapt to do what you want.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt would you guys be interested in a pull request to this effect?  there are many matlab users transitioning to python, so i do think there is fairly wide demand for this, but i'd understand if you'd rather not have code that copies matlab without independent justification.

Comment: I think if this is a useful feature and there is no reason why we shouldn't implement it.  Just be careful not to look at any code written under a different license while doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You should first pass the Canny parameters to `canny()` and then run it in your Python code

im: image name
lower threshold: 
upper threshold:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
edges = cv2.Canny(img,....,....,L2gradient=False/True)

plt.imshow(edges,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! I have edited your answer to use proper formatting. You can always [edit] your answer to further improve it. Please take a look at what I did to format, and take a note of it for your next answer. You can use a subset of Markdown for formatting. Also the buttons along the top of the editor window will insert these formatting elements. I am sort of I did something wrong while exiting, please feel free to fix it up!

Comment: i don't see how this answers the question.